# A single function that does CRUD in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

> I want to create a function for doing all kind of CRUD operation. This function will be called from any controller's inside a function. Then the function will search for a table/Model, then based on operation type it will do the rest things.

It will be good to implement this kind of function that can be used commonly? It will increase the complexity of CRUD? Or, should do the CRUD in controllers' functions?
My project is pretty big. Im thinking to write a function to do CRUD.

Comment: From my experience, it's best to stick with the standards. E.g. Laravel resource routes, policies and much more, depends on such standards. Any particular reason for combining CRUD into 1 operation?

Comment: The reason is to skip the hard coded lines of code. For example: For creating a resource, three steps have to be done. Instance create by calling Model, map fields value & save finally. This things i have to do so many times in every where for create operation. As reasult, development time takes longer. Thats why i want a single finction which will do the job dynamically for me. I will call the function with 3 params (operationType, table_model_name, data). The function will do the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

You should consider using a controller, like ProductsController, and inside it, you should have a funcion for every action (store, update, etc).

Doing all of this in a single function only adds unnecessary complexity to the project and this isn't how things should be done.

As a starting point, execute this command on you project: `php artisan make:controller ProductsController --resource`. This will create an well structured controller for Products CRUD actions.

Hope you find this helpfull.

Comment: You didnt get my point. Ultimately i have to write logics for CRUD on each CRUD operations. What i meant, lets say using resource for create i have to create a instance, then map fields value n finally save(). Same thing i have to write hard coded in another Resource controller for same purpose. I want to create a function which will do the job for me dynamically.

Comment: No, you can simply use ```Products::create($request->all())```. Make sure all form fields are on Products Model on ```$fillable``` array. Note that I'm not using custom formRequest to validate data (required, numeric, etc).